# how to convert an array to hex value

Tags: c, arrays, file

I am trying to print the hex value of an array, but I am getting an error.

Code I have tried:

```
char Routing[29];
memset(&Routing,0x00,29);
chdir("\\WWW");
tp = fopen("routing.csv", "a");
    if(tp!=NULL){
        if (SlaveNodeID != 0x00){
            fseek(tp, (98 * SlaveNodeID), SEEK_SET);
            fprintf(tp, "\n %058x,",Routing);
        }
```

OUTPUT GOT:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a001ff30
```

But i need an OUTPUT of

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I don't know why I am getting this  `a001ff30` value..

Comment: perhaps the value you're reading contains it.

Comment: +1, good question. Improvement suggestion: Code examples should be complete, but *as minimal as possible to demonstrate the problem*. In your case, lines 3-7 could be replaced with the single line `printf("%058x", Routing);`. That way, everyone can easily execute your code without the need for a `\\WWW` directory.

Comment: You need to print the contents of Routing rather than it's address.

Answer (score 2):

You need to print out each byte of the array that you read instead

so instead of

```
fprintf(tp, "\n %058x,",Routing);
```

do

```
fprintf( tp, "\n " );
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(Routing); ++i)
{
  fprintf( tp, "02x", Routing[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `char Routing[29];` creates an array of 29 characters and sets the address of this array to the variable Routing.  `fprintf(tp, "\n %058x,",Routing);` prints out a 0 padded value of Routing, which is the address of the character array.  You need to iterate over the array and print out each value individually.

```cpp
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(Routing); i++) {
    fprintf (tp, "%02x", Routing[i]);
}
```

With warnings enabled in gcc, you should see that this is an issue: `warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to display every character in the array is as follows. I am providing a skeleton code. You can fill in the blanks yourself.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int array[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%x\n", array[i]);
    }
}
```